# Move Edittext little bit upward when softkeypad pop in

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

My current view is like this. I want to move my Edittext field bit upwards since half of it hidden by the soft keyboard. How can I do this in android ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I think, [This will work for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541862/make-an-edit-text-appear-between-the-top-and-the-soft-keyboard-of-the-device-in/11544908#11544908)

Comment: Have you seen/ tried above link??

Comment: I'm trying the above link. Will give an update.

Comment: @Chintan you link didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
   android:gravity="center_vertical">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"                
        android:text="Username"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/editUsername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"   
        android:padding="10dp"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row3"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="password"               
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</TableRow> 
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/editPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"      
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"   
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"        
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:password="true"                
        android:singleLine="true"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row6"            
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="login"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"/>
</TableRow> 
  </TableLayout>
```